# Jade/pug anchor tag newline confusion

Tags: javascript, html, pug, href

I am using Jade/Pug and I want the following "a" tag to appear on the same line as the preceding "p" tag text but whatever I do the link always appears underneath the text. How can I stop this?

```
for option in responseBody.options
    p
        |#{option.courseType}
        |#{option.subject}
        a(href='/formdash/{responseBody.formId}/{responseBody.studentId}/{option._id}/options') Delete
```

Comment: Could you please add compiled html in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly where your issue lies, because I've tried to reproduce this with [a CodePen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/qPqQwj), but it works as expected there... For reference, this is what I constructed to try to reproduce your issue:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]
p
    |#{i}
    |#{i}
    a(href='#') Delete
```

Comment: As soon as I read this I realised the problem. This is embarrassing. There was some CSS at play that I had forgotten about :/